# The image stored in database base64 format how can retrieve it back in its original format in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've stored the image in the base64 format in the database (stored formate: **data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR** ) now I want back image from database using PHP, I used all the method but doesn't work.

my current method is

[image]

Comment: Please write your code as text instead of using image.

Comment: You say you stored the image as base 64 encoded string in the DB. So why then do you base64_encode it AGAIN in your echo?

Comment: BTW you are much better saving the image in a folder, and storing the path to the image in the DB ;-)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is read the base64 from db and use it to create an image file, here is a function to create jpeg image from base64

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64, $jpeg) {

    $fp = fopen($jpeg, 'wb'); 
    $data = explode(',', $base64);
    fwrite($fp, base64_decode($data[1]));
    fclose( $fp ); 

    return $jpeg; 
}
```

and the function will return the jpeg file object

Comment: I have to do for multiple image because i stored multiple images

Comment: you can get all the base^4 strings and put it in a loop, then call this function, it will create each of these images

Answer (score 0):

***May be this solution works for you:***

[How to decode a base64 string (gif) into image in PHP / HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110907/how-to-decode-a-base64-string-gif-into-image-in-php-html)

Quoting that source but modifying:
In the case you strip out the first case and choose to decode the string, you should add this before echoing the decoded image data:

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$data = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD........";
echo base64_decode($data);
```

In the second case, use this instead:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $data . '" />';
```

The second case is bad because the browser does not perform caching if the same image is shown on multiple pages.